# How to pass controller observed property in component

Tags: ember.js, ember-components

I am working on an application where I am passing a property that is being observed in controller, to the component but I am getting **undefined** value. I am using ember 1.6

How I call **component**:-

```
{{range-slider min="0" max="100" step="1" value=currentVal}}
```

**Component** implementation is:-

```
App.RangeSliderComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
tagName:'',
currentValue:function(){
    return this.get('value');
}.property('value'),

minValue:function(){
    return this.get('min');
}.property('min'),

didInsertElement:function(){
    console.log("component with currentValue="+this.get("currentValue")+" minValue="+this.get('minValue'));

}
```

})

**currentVal** used as component value is a property being observed in controller. Whenever I slide the slider, the currentVal is changed as it is bound with the component. The default value is 50. Controller is working fine.

The **controller** part is:-

```
currentVal:50,

currentValChanged:function(){
    console.log("currentVal changed");
}.observes('currentVal'),
```

In component, I am getting the **min** value correctly but not getting the **value**. It's coming undefined.

How to get the property **value** in component?

**Update**

I am able to get variable by following methods in component:-
1) If I pass a variable directly to component with static value, it works.
e.g the **max** value passed in range-slider component.
2) If I pass a static variable that is defined in controller
e.g. in controller

```
dummyValue:2345,
```

If I pass dummy value to component, I can read it in component part.

But if the **property is computed property** then it's not working.

Comment: So is `currentValue` anything different from an alias, which you can define more simply with `currentValue: Ember.computed.alias('value')`? Whether or not your controller is observing some property should have nothing to do with anything.

Comment: it's not working even with computed.alias()

Comment: Just a guess, but there could be some issue with the property name `value`, try changing it to `val`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt your controller is setting undefined value to currentVal property in controller part.   Please have a look at the [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/31f40c4ee3e0c475edce22a8d2b8b85d?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C) which is working..

Comment: Thanks. That really helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you do `value=currentVal` you have to access it `this.get("value")`. If you want to access it with `this.get("currentValue")` then you need to pass it with that name: `currentValue= currentVal`.

Comment: this.get("value") is not working. And currentValue is computed property in component. this.get("value") should work in currentValue property but it's not working.

Comment: can you provide a non working ember-twiddle? it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I hope to not sound very stupid but, did you try to put an space between `currentVal` and `}}`? It **seriously** worked for me with some helpers.

Like this:

```
{{range-slider min="0" max="100" step="1" value=currentVal }}
```

Really, I **need** to do that with ember-xselect or it doesn't work properly.

Comment: This seems very unlikely.

Comment: @torazaburo Yes I know, and if I were in your position probably would think that's stupid, but its really needed with ember-xselect so I though that may be a generalized problem with Handlebars when writing variable names or assignment expressions next to the closing `}}`.